# Google JsonFactory (JacksonFactory) fromString not working - all fields are null

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an object:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class OauthPrincipal {
    @JsonProperty
    String id;

    @JsonProperty
    String name;

    @JsonProperty
    String email;

    public OauthPrincipal() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    ... other [get|set]ters
}
```

Which works when I do:

```
final String jsonIdentity = request.execute().parseAsString();
debug(jsonIdentity);
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
OauthPrincipal o;
o = om.readValue(jsonIdentity, OauthPrincipal.class);
return o;
```

But when I use JsonFactory (Which is a `new JacksonFactory()` all fields are null for the same JSON

`jf.fromString(json, OauthPrincipal.class`

JSON from log is :

```
07:31:44,040 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  {
07:31:44,040 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  "id": "11",
07:31:44,040 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  "email": "example@gmail.com",
07:31:44,040 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  "verified_email": true,
07:31:44,040 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  "name": "mike",
07:31:44,040 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  "given_name": "mike",
07:31:44,040 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  "family_name": "b",
07:31:44,040 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  "link": "https://plus.google.com/xyz",
07:31:44,040 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/snipped/photo.jpg",
07:31:44,040 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6)  "locale": "en"
07:31:44,040 ERROR [stderr] (default task-6) }
```

Comment: 1/ jackson is not from Google, 2/ can you please post an [mcve] showing your `JacksonFactory` usage and specify what jackson version do you use?

Comment: Right, Jackson is not google, but it is worth mentioning since it's using Jackson for the parsing (creating the JsonFactory with a new JacksonFactory()) and since the OjbectMapper (which is Jackson) works.

Answer (score 0):

Google's [Client Library JSON](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/json) shows `@Key` notation usage:

```
public class Item {
  @Key
  public String id;
  @Key
  public String value;
}
```

I had the same issue with JsonFactory ( JacksonFactory underneath ), using `@Key` notation in my class definition solved it.